# How do I pass values to an Argo Workflow of Workflows?

Tags: continuous-integration, argo-workflows

I want to implement a generic CI pattern using Argo Workflows. One Workflow is triggered by the git server using an Argo Events webhook. After validating the signature, the repo is cloned and a custom workflow from the git repo is started (with a fixed name, e.g. `.argo-ci.yaml`). The Workflow of Workflows pattern is recommended to be implemented using the [template.resource field](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/examples/workflow-of-workflows.yaml). When using the `manifest` key, I can use input variables as shown in the example. However, variables are not evaluated using `manifestFrom`, which I would need to start the Workflow from git.

For a CI use case, the child workflow either needs to be passed the git repo artifact or at least the git revision as a variable so that the Workflow can clone and checkout the correct sources for which the CI was triggered. Both does not seem to be possible as the manifest from `template.resource.manifestFrom` is applied as-is without templating options.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a git question.